# Can I roast nuts in a convection microwave oven?

Tags: equipment, microwave, roasting, nuts

I am looking for a new microwave. I heard a lot of good things about convection microwave ovens. I am wondering if I could also use one for roasting nuts or any kind of seeds, so I don't have to buy another appliance for roasting nuts and seeds.

Comment: Agreed, duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

just toast them in a saute pan on low to medium heat youl achieve the same effect.

if you must use your microwave convection, you shouldn't use the "microwave" aspect of it and simply the convection.  Any use of the convection will increase your electricity substantially.